# OAuth - Login With Moodle

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-chrome-extension, openid, moodle

I am building a chrome extension for a school, and it needs to authenticate with moodle, meaning that I need a OAuth or OpenID like setup, I open a page to moodle, the user then logs in/approves the app, and then a token is returned, which I can then use for normal moodle web service calls. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has a similar issue when trying to authenticate an extension using oauth, the flow I used was first check if we have tokens stored: if not then open a new tab from a background page, which means it will be ran when the extension is first installed, although if the token is there we go on to run our requests, but I asked the user to close the tab after the approval has been completed, which I set a listener for after it was created, then I knew that the process was complete and I could make requests.

If you need any code for sections of this, I'd be happy to post.

Good Luck

Update:

check if we have tokens saved :

```
if(localStorage.token){
    if(localStorage.secret){
```

if not :

```
else{
    var authURL = bgOauth.requestTokenCall();
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    req.onload = bgOauth.processRequestTokenData;
    req.open("get", authURL, true);
    req.send();
    console.log('sent')
}
```

then I process the response from this, if all good then I open a new tab:

```
startPopup : function(destinationurl) {

    chrome.tabs.create({url : destinationurl}, 
    function(tab){bgOauth.newTabId = tab.id})
    alert(Instructions)     
    chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId)
    {
        console.log('oh no, closed');
        if(tabId == bgOauth.newTabId){
            console.log('freaking sweet!');
            bgOauth.handleApproval()
        }   
        else{
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Then I can finish the authorization process, and preform requests be sure to save your credentials in localStorage.

Comment: I Am not quite sure what you mean, and yes, code would be very helpful.

Comment: what is `bgOauth`, and what is authURL?

Comment: bgOauth is a small collection of Oauth methods I made to handle generating Oauth URL's as they need to be signed. The authURL is the URL generated from the above description, it is what I then send the request to, this might be different for you, I have no experience with moodle.